# Unique page depending on id

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to add a unique page for each row in database. so when i click video.php?id=1

it will show the page of the row where the id=1

i have tried with following code, but it just give me the error: unexpected T_VARIABLE

my code is following:

```
<?php 
include "connect.php"; 

$id = $_GET['id']
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE id='".$id."' ");

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {


        <? echo $row[name]; ?>
        <? echo $row[title]; ?>


   }

?>
```

Comment: Your error message should also contain a line number where the error occurs.

Comment: also, you do not need the '<?' and '?>' inside of your `while` loop. actually i'm surprised it doesn't throw an error there. you're already executing php so no need for the open tag again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add a semicolon here

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
-----------------^
```

**EDIT :**

Change your echo variables from

```
<? echo $row[name]; ?>
<? echo $row[title]; ?>
```

to

```
echo $row['name'];
echo $row['title'];
```

Tips :

- Don't use **`mysql_`** functions, as they will be deprecated soon. Make use of **`PDO`** or **`MySQLi`**
- Try to sanitize the variables before you directly send it inside the query.

Comment: Thank you, but now it just give me a blank page? any ideas why it wont print out $name and $title ?

thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semi-colon:

```
$id = $_GET['id'] // <-- here it is missing
```

should be:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Answer (score -1):

use:
https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

and try to debug the result like:

```
var_dump($row);
```

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string? how?